# Is there a problem with my circuit?

Tags: transistors, ltspice, schematics, bipolar

[image]

The problem is that the curve of the collector's current decreases after reaching a certain (or saturation) point. Should it be this way or there is a problem with LTspice?

Comment: Welcome! Please put a resistor in series with the base or change V1 from voltage to current source.

Comment: Are you aware that you're *far* beyond the absolute maximum collector current for that transistor? [The datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/BCW60C-1305165.pdf) says 100 mA max. I wouldn't worry about what happens when you give it a 13x overload--a real one would have melted by then anyway.

Comment: You get results that are not realistic because the circuit is not realistic. The simulator does not care if the circuit is not realistic.

Comment: I suspect you want to do something [more like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N4rt.png) with LTspice.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a problem with the circuit. When you drive the base from a voltage source, a very large current will flow from base to emitter, and (e.g. above 1 V), this will raise the internal emitter voltage because of the I*R drop on emitter resistance. This in turn raises the internal collector voltage, and so reduces the total collector-emitter current.

This is not a normal (or useful) bias level for a transistor.

Answer (score -2):

There is a problem with LTspice because it assumes that the current curve stays the same after reaching saturation. However, this is not always true and can be misleading. In reality, as the collector's current rises above saturation, its curve will start to decrease until it reaches a new equilibrium point. This can lead to erroneous results if you use LTspice to model electrical circuits.

Comment: LTspice uses E-M model for BJT or equivalent and solves numerically. It does not assume anything.